# How to correctly insert data in cosmos with pyspark dataframe?

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, azure-cosmosdb

I'm trying to insert a dataframe pyspark into cosmosdb...
I downloaded the "com.microsoft.azure_azure-cosmosdb-spark_2.3.0_2.11-1.3.3.jar" like indicate in the doc: https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmosdb-spark/blob/2.4/README.md
Then I config my sparkSession like this:

```
spark = SparkSession.builder \
          .config("spark.driver.extraClassPath", "C:/Users/Cris243/.ivy2/jars/")\
          .config("spark.jars", "com.microsoft.azure_azure-cosmosdb-spark_2.3.0_2.11-1.3.3.jar") \
          .appName('Spark') \
          .getOrCreate()
```

but when i try to write in cosmos with my config, i get a "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.microsoft.azure.cosmosdb.spark.DefaultSource" like this:

```
Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[16], line 13
      1 writeConfig3 = {
      2     
      3     "Endpoint": "https://localhost:8081/",
   (...)
      8     
      9 }
     11 # df = test.coalesce(1)
---> 13 df.write.format("com.microsoft.azure.cosmosdb.spark").mode("overwrite").options(**writeConfig3).save()

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pyspark\sql\readwriter.py:966, in DataFrameWriter.save(self, path, format, mode, partitionBy, **options)
    964     self.format(format)
    965 if path is None:
--> 966     self._jwrite.save()
    967 else:
    968     self._jwrite.save(path)

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\py4j\java_gateway.py:1321, in JavaMember.__call__(self, *args)
   1315 command = proto.CALL_COMMAND_NAME +\
   1316     self.command_header +\
   1317     args_command +\
   1318     proto.END_COMMAND_PART
   1320 answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
-> 1321 return_value = get_return_value(
   1322     answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
   1324 for temp_arg in temp_args:
   1325     temp_arg._detach()

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pyspark\sql\utils.py:190, in capture_sql_exception.<locals>.deco(*a, **kw)
    188 def deco(*a: Any, **kw: Any) -> Any:
    189     try:
--> 190         return f(*a, **kw)
    191     except Py4JJavaError as e:
    192         converted = convert_exception(e.java_exception)

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\py4j\protocol.py:326, in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    324 value = OUTPUT_CONVERTER[type](answer[2:], gateway_client)
    325 if answer[1] == REFERENCE_TYPE:
--> 326     raise Py4JJavaError(
    327         "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
    328         format(target_id, ".", name), value)
    329 else:
    330     raise Py4JError(
    331         "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}. Trace:\n{3}\n".
    332         format(target_id, ".", name, value))

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o113.save.
: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
Failed to find data source: com.microsoft.azure.cosmosdb.spark. Please find packages at
https://spark.apache.org/third-party-projects.html
       
    at org.apache.spark.sql.errors.QueryExecutionErrors$.failedToFindDataSourceError(QueryExecutionErrors.scala:587)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$.lookupDataSource(DataSource.scala:675)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$.lookupDataSourceV2(DataSource.scala:725)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.lookupV2Provider(DataFrameWriter.scala:864)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveInternal(DataFrameWriter.scala:256)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:247)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:578)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.waitForCommands(ClientServerConnection.java:182)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.run(ClientServerConnection.java:106)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1589)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.microsoft.azure.cosmosdb.spark.DefaultSource
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:445)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:588)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$.$anonfun$lookupDataSource$5(DataSource.scala:661)
    at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:213)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$.$anonfun$lookupDataSource$4(DataSource.scala:661)
    at scala.util.Failure.orElse(Try.scala:224)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$.lookupDataSource(DataSource.scala:661)
    ... 14 more
```

My code:

```
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf, SQLContext
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession.builder \
          .config("spark.driver.extraClassPath", "C:/Users/Cris243/.ivy2/jars/")\
          .config("spark.jars", "com.microsoft.azure_azure-cosmosdb-spark_2.3.0_2.11-1.3.3.jar") \
          .appName('Spark') \
          .getOrCreate()

df = (
    spark.read.option("header", True).csv("crypto.csv")
     .select(
         col("rank"),
         col("symbol"),
         col("name"),
         col("priceUsd"),
         col("volumeUsd24Hr"))
     )

writeConfig3 = {
    
    "Endpoint": "https://localhost:8081/",
    "Masterkey": "C2y6yDjf5/R+ob0N8A7Cgv30VRDJIWEHLM+4QDU5DE2nQ9nDuVTqobD4b8mGGyPMbIZnqyMsEcaGQy67XIw/Jw==",
    "Database": "cryptos",
    "Collection": "symbol",
    "Upsert": "true"
    
}

df.write.format("com.microsoft.azure.cosmosdb.spark").mode("overwrite").options(**writeConfig3).save()
```

I tried to add also a "spark.jars.ivy" like this:
("spark.jars.ivy", "C:/Users/Cris243/.ivy2/jars/")" but i get the same error

Can someone help explain how to fix it ?
Grateful

Comment: Are you limited to using Spark 2? If not, why not use the newer Spark 3 connector? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/nosql/sdk-java-spark-v3

Answer (score 0):

> Failed to find data source: com.microsoft.azure.cosmosdb.spark. Please find packages at https://spark.apache.org/third-party-projects.html

**The cause of the error is the spark application is not able to detect the libraries in the jar file.**

Spark programmers can make use of the libraries. After the application has been created, the   [spark-submit](https://sparkbyexamples.com/spark/spark-submit-command/#:%7E:text=The%20spark-submit%20command%20is,submit%20command%20supports%20the%20following.) command is used to submit it for execution in the Spark environment.

- **Use --jars option**
  To add JARs to a Spark job, --jars option can be used to include JARs on Spark driver and executor classpaths. If multiple JAR files need to be included, use comma to separate them.

**The following is an example:**

```py
spark-submit --jars /path/to/jar/file1
```